# Image resize excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro where I am resizing an image.
What should happen: an image is located inside the cell and when I click it once it enlarges, and when I click it again it goes back to normal.
But when I click the image to return it to normal it does not it, goes out of the cell.
The code is below and an image to see what happens when I have clicked an image

```
Sub Picture1_Click()
Dim shp As Shape
    Dim big As Single, small As Single
    Dim shpDouH As Double, shpDouOriH As Double
    big = 3
    small = 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With shp
        shpDouH = .Height
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        shpDouOriH = .Height
     
        If Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2) = big Then
            .ScaleHeight small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
        Else
            .ScaleHeight big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

How can I reset the image to what it was previously?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the use of ScaleHeight. This method resizes the image in relation to its *current* size, so `.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft` does nothing; it basically resizes the image to the size it already has.

Read more about ScaleHeight here: [Shape.ScaleHeight method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.scaleheight)

As your code is written, `shpDouH` will always be equal to `shpDouOriH`, which means that `Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2)` will always calculate to exactly 1. That defeats your `If ... Then ... Else` logic. Each time you click, the image size will increase by a scale factor of 3; it will never shrink.

The easiest way to shrink the image back to its original dimensions is if you are able to define the maximum dimensions for an un-enlarged image. Then you can use a test along the lines of `If shp.Height > MaxHeight Then`. In basic concept, if the current height is less than MaxHeight, then scale by a factor of 3; else scale by a factor of 1/3. This should work if the original images are all roughly the same size.

Otherwise you will need to pick a method to record the original dimensions before each image is enlarged.